# How can I flag an offensive post on a locked question?

Tags: support, flags, moderation, locked-posts

I have encountered a highly offensive (but upvoted) post.

The problem is, it's an answer on a locked question (on MSO) and locked questions don't have a flag option.

I can't even flag some other post by the same user and put the link to the offensive post into the flag; since that was the user's only MSO post.

What should be done in such a situation?

Comment: I would prefer not to post the link to the post directly, because it seems wrong to air a flag in public

Comment: If you cannot flag it and you don't want to disclose it here, then I'm afraid there's nothing we can do. Maybe consider chat or direct email to the team?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - (1) it's not that bad that it's worth hassling the team over. I just want a mod to look at it and make a judgement call and hopefully take action. (2) More importantly, I'm asking a general question of how such a situation should be handled.

Comment: Just flag one of your own posts, provide a link and explain exactly the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @Mat - done. You may want to post as an answer.

Comment: A "_highly_ offensive" (emphasis mine) but _upvoted_ post? Make sure your offense-o-meter is calibrated.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: "high" "up" I don't see a problem ;)

Comment: Didn't Shog write something a little while ago about moderating while intoxicated, @BoltClock?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whenever you need to bring a mod's attention to something you can't flag (user that has no posts left, locked post, deleted post you can't see but have a link to, stray unicorn in your garden, etc.), flag one of your own posts and explain in detail (with links) the problem you're seeing.

As always, be as clear and concise as you can. A few words at the very beginning stating that your flag isn't about the post you're flagging would probably be a good thing, to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Note that starting such a flag with `Stray unicorn in your garden:` would be hilarious in retrospect, although I would not recommend doing that.

Comment: I, for one, would welcome a stray unicorn in my garden (if I had a garden).

Comment: @jpmc26 - according to Ministry of Magic classification, unicorns are classified "XXXX", dangerous.