# Locked question requires editing

Tags: discussion, flags, locked-posts

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top), and the accepted answer has a dead link. Because this question is locked I can't edit the question. Doing some digging I could only [find this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219878/locked-question-with-bad-accepted-answer-on-stackoverflow-can-it-be-deleted) about locked question:

> If you have a justifiable reason that a post should be unlocked, you should flag it for moderator attention using the "flag" link underneath the post. Select the "other" flag reason, and provide a detailed explanation of your rationale in the textbox provided.

Where is that "flag" link? I don't have it. Also why is there any other way (other than sending message to person that locked the question) to suggest an edit?

Comment: related/dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254392/how-can-i-flag-an-offensive-post-on-a-locked-question

Comment: I've removed the last paragraph for now. If you can find the link in way back machine or the Internet archive a mod will be able to edit it in.

Comment: @Jon Clements this link seems to be the same one because the number 9275 in both paths indicate that they are the same https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09275/

Comment: @Raxvan updated - thanks.